# Elasticsearch Marvel Agent how to reinitialize after "Skipping exporter"

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-marvel

I have two separate clusters for ES. One is simply Production cluster, second one is Development Cluster where I store Marvel data for Production one to use within Kibana.

Due to some Data Center network issues at one point this two clusters couldn't connect to each other which resulted in some errors like Connection Timeout and finally in:

```
[2016-12-16 10:29:13,609][INFO ][marvel.agent.exporter    ] [els-hdp202] skipping exporter [snr_monitoring] as it isn't ready yet
```

After fixing connection issues, is there possibility to restore this exporter without restarting Elasticsearch service?

- Elasticsearch version: 2.4.1
- Marvel agent version: 2.4.1